# ¿Como crear un archivo .sql que muestre un script en Sql Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo la siguiente duda. Estoy haciendo comparaciones con dos bases de datos desde una sp que creé. Lo que necesito es, una vez que se haga todas las comparaciones, generar un archivo *.sql* donde dentro tenga el script que va a modificar la base de datos destino para que sean iguales.

Además se tendría que abrir automaticamente cuando termina con el sp, como por ejemplo en una tabla cualquiera se hace click derecho select top row 1000 y se abre un script con el select.

Comment: Así cómo está, la pregunta es muy amplia. Si nos muestras cómo estás generando el archivo con las comparaciones y qué es lo que te falta, es más fácil ayudar. 
Lo de que se abra automático, depende del cliente que uses.

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos `.sql` son simples archivos de texto asociados a Management Studio. Para crearlos, sólo tienes que guardar el script y asegurarte de que la extesión es la correcta.